# Why is this shown when I'm trying ask a question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

[image: buggy]

It says "your answer couldn't be...".

I tried posting a **question** on meta and not an answer. A bug perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (rev `2015.2.20.2330`).

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the message is wrong. It should say "question" instead of "answer". You should put this bug report up on Meta.SE.

As for the warning itself, meta questions must have one of the tags [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [support](/questions/tagged/support), so it's by design.

Comment: No need to put up bugs on Meta.SE specifically - we monitor reports on all sites.